# How to use DependencyProperty in user Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I want to create a user control that can recieve a parameter via xaml.

i search and tried a few things, bu none of them seems to work for me.
i'm attaching the important code.
My user control Code (only the dependency property):

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty DatabaseNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "DatabaseName", typeof(string), typeof(TablesForm), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange));
    public string DatabaseName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DatabaseNameProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(DatabaseNameProperty, value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("DatabaseName");
        }
    }
```

The call From Main Window:

```
<StackPanel>
     <local:TablesForm DatabaseName="Testing"/>
</StackPanel>
```

When i put in the user control construcor the string directly into the dependencyProperty it works.
It would be great if can someone explain the logic behind (and help me with my problem)

Thank for the help.

Comment: `NotifyPropertyChanged("DatabaseName");` makes me hesitate. why do you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` when inheriting from `DependencyObject`? be aware, that setting `DatabaseName="Testing"` does not use your property-wrapper's setter. it directly calls `DependencyObject.SetValue(...)`

Comment: you right i don't need NotifyPropertyChanged("DatabaseName"); can you please elaborate about the "be aware" part? did you mean that it automatically calls the setter and nor goes inside what i wrote?

Comment: try to display a MessageBox in the setter. it won't show when assigning a value to the property via XAML. and yes, that is because the framework directly calls SetValue instead of calling your setter

Comment: First of all, thank you for the reply.  How can i solve the problem all i want to do is to pass a prameter from MainWindow to user control and have the ability to use it in the user control. and all the transformation of the parameter must be via xaml?

Comment: I attached a minimal code example on how to create a usercontrol using DependencyProperties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work, all i've missed is to add impelementation to Propertycallbackchanged. i didn't have to set the element name. I mean, all i had to do is to change:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DatabaseNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "DatabaseName", typeof(string), typeof(TablesForm), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange));
```

To this:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty DatabaseNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "DatabaseName", typeof(string), typeof(TablesForm), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(String.Empty, OnCurrentTimePropertyChanged));
```

and implement OnCurrentTimePropertyChanged

```
private static void OnCurrentTimePropertyChanged(DependencyObject source,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TablesForm control = source as TablesForm;
        control.m_viewModel.Log = (string)e.NewValue;            
    }
```

This will help me to manipulate the DependencyProperty.

Thank @Benj for the help.

Answer (score 0):

A working implementation of a UserControl is this

**XAML UserControl1**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Name="_this"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="LightGray" Text="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=DatabaseName}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**CSharp UserControl1**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DatabaseNameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register
            (
                @"DatabaseName",
                typeof(String),
                typeof(UserControl1),
                new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty)
            );
        public String DatabaseName
        {
            get { return GetValue(DatabaseNameProperty) as String; }
            set { SetValue(DatabaseNameProperty, value); }
        }

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML TestWindow**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        >
    <Grid>
        <local:UserControl1 DatabaseName="Database_Test" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**CSharp TestWindow**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank i use the implemetation and it does work so thank you very much but but before print it i need to do someting on it (does'nt matter what as long it is in the user control) and the why i need the DatabaseName property to get him. in your example i add a viewmodel that has string call Log and the Log take the databaseName:                             m_viewModel.Log = DatabaseName; of course the log is with propertychange event:      private string m_log = null;
public string Log
{
get { return m_log; }
set
{
m_log = value;
NotifyPropertyChanged("Log");
}
}